# Google Maps API key over query limit before a single geocode has been made

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

My site is hosted by rackspace and I understand that is a constant problem for Google Maps API users, so I setup an API key as described in the [Google Geolocation documentation here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#auth)

I tried then taking the link and directly putting it into my browser to see what was produced and this is what I got back:

URL Tested where XXXXXX is the API Key:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3750+Barranca+Pkwy+Irvine%2C+CA+92606&sensor=false&region=US&key=XXXXXX
```

Yields this message:

```
"error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid.",
"results" : [],
"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
```

I am using Codeigniter and [Biostall's Google v3 Api](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library) to get the maps to work. However, even with the key in place, I still get the "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" error.

Is there some kind of activation time I have to wait for Google API keys to be made active or some reason why Google would not recognize I'm not using the IP's count of map reads, but I should be on my own count? Will it even work like that?

Please help, I am not seeing a solution online and the Google support puts me here.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The [query works without the key](https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3750+Barranca+Pkwy+Irvine%2C+CA+92606&sensor=false&region=US).  What kind of key is it? Is it a browser key or a server key?  How did you configure the referers?  FYI - I get the same result as you do with the [link you posted](https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3750+Barranca+Pkwy+Irvine%2C+CA+92606&sensor=false&region=US&key=XXXXXX), which probably means it is correct about your key being invalid.

Comment: So I've made new keys and tried it with them but I still have no geocoding. Why is that?

Comment: Don't know, you didn't answer any of my questions. How did you configure the new keys?

Comment: Hi Mike. Firstly no geocoding URLs I try work with a key provided so I think let's get rid of the key for now. My first question therefore is, does the URL work you've provided without a key? The next thing to check is the URL. The geocoding URL differs slightly on the Google documentation and looks like so: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3750+Barranca+Pkwy+Irvine%2C+CA+92606&sensor=false&region=US. Can you please check if that URL works for you? It's working fine from my end. Let me know :)

Comment: @geocodezip: The kind of key is a Browser Key. Originally, I set the referers to *.url.com and url.com and the exact domain it was alpha.url.com. Then I saw it wasn't working and took all referers away entirely.

Comment: If you are trying to use it as a web service, I would think it would need to be a server key, not a browser key.

Comment: @BIOSTALL: I took out the key in the URL out and that is working now. However in the app, I am getting that same error that I did in this question I asked: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061445/codeigniter-google-maps-api-v3-geocoding-not-working/19069580?noredirect=1#comment28186770_19069580) It seems like Google is still blocking me from using geocoding and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hi Mike. If you look in the library, in the function get_lat_long_from_address() it doesn't pass the API key in the geocoding URL. Can you confirm you haven't manually modified this at all?

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. I've added a 2 second delay and it gives me the over the limit error, even though I know I'm not over that limit (as it works occasionally).

Answer (score 1):

The Google Geocoding API requires no key [**Documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index) for non business users.

The API limits non business users to 2,500 requests per day.(No key)

And business users to 100,000 requests per day.(Business key required)

I assume the key you entered is [**This**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key)

Comment: Yes, that is the way I got the key. I have since taken the key out but I'm still getting the same OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error.