# google maps api, The provided API key is invalid

Tags: google-maps, url, geocoding

This is my first time posting a question on stack overflow, really hoping you guys can help.

I am trying to use the google maps geocodeing api for the first time and cannot get it to work.

The url format I am using is:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=LS2+9AQ&sensor=false&key=[MY_API_KEY]

In this case I am looking up the uk postcode: LS2 9AQ from a chrome browser.

The url does work when I don't use my api key but the limit on the number of allowed calls without the key is too low for my needs.

I am not yet using this in a production site, for now it is running from my local dev in chrome.

The actual response I get is:

```
[error_message] => The provided API key is invalid.
[results] => Array
    (
    )

    [status] => REQUEST_DENIED
```

When I remove the api key it works and returns the following:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "LS2 9AQ",
               "short_name" : "LS2 9AQ",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Woodhouse",
               "short_name" : "Woodhouse",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Leeds",
               "short_name" : "Leeds",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "West Yorkshire",
               "short_name" : "West York",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
               "short_name" : "GB",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Leeds",
               "short_name" : "Leeds",
               "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Woodhouse, Leeds, West Yorkshire LS2 9AQ, UK",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 53.8090296,
                  "lng" : -1.5509549
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 53.8083045,
                  "lng" : -1.5519655
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 53.808447,
               "lng" : -1.5517752
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 53.81001603029149,
                  "lng" : -1.550111219708498
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 53.80731806970849,
                  "lng" : -1.552809180291502
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I have tried replacing the url with one that is currently in use on my works website and I got the same response, I have tried two different keys that I generated myself, one created last week and the other created an hour ago.  I have set up the keys in the following way:

- payment is enabled and a credit card is attached to the project (I was told this was needed to increase limit on api's by validating identity)
- on one key referrer is set to "dev.test.com/*" (this is the url I am using on my local dev for this).  On the other key no referrer is specified.
- the key is a browser apps key

I am definitely entering the key properly, both me and another developer have checked this multiple times, does anyone have any ideas on what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance to anyone that helps.

**UPDATE**
I have found the problem that was causing the process to stop working after 10 iterations.  The google geocoding api has a limit of 10 calls per second in place and I was going over this, I have now added in a 1 second delay every 10 iterations and I can now in theory reach the daily limit.

However I still need more calls than the default free limit, as described in my comments below I believe I can use an api key to increase the free limit based on me having a verified account.  I am using this for business but it is not high enough volume to be worth paying for it.  Can anyone help clear this up for me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API key over query limit before a single geocode has been made](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129910/google-maps-api-key-over-query-limit-before-a-single-geocode-has-been-made)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate as his problem may be caused by rackspace, we don't use them for hosting and right now the problem is on my local dev machine.  Also I am not getting the "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error" from that question nor am using Codeigniter and Biostall's Google v3 Api

Comment: So what do I do to get this answered? this isn't a duplicate but no-one seems to be looking at it because of that flag at the top...

Comment: I don't  understand what in this statement in the answer to that question isn't clear "The Google Geocoding API requires no key for non business users." (and doesn't work if you add one).

Comment: Google's Geocoding API is free for non-business users. Limit is 2500 calls a day. API call has no key! - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters

Comment: when I run this without an api key I only get 10 results before it stops working, I am looping through multiple address.  Also I am using this for business and I need the high allocation of calls. Sorry If I should have mentioned that before.

Comment: For further clarification, I saw the usage limits here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search Where a 10 times multiplier is mentioned in regard to these calls.
In this page:
https://developers.google.com/places/policies#usage_limits
it mentions "Users who have verified their identity through the APIs console are allowed 100 000 requests per 24 hour period. A credit card is required for verification, by enabling billing in the console"

Comment: hit the character limit there...
This is why I have been trying to make this work with an API key, to get the higher allocation that comes with validating your identity (which I have done)

Have I misunderstood something here, is there another way to identify myself apart from api keys or is this documentation referring to something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, It looks like what I was trying to do is impossible without paying for a business account.  There is no way to apply an apikey to the google geocoding api.

I had misunderstood some documentation regarding the google maps api which referred to raising the allowed limit on daily queries.

This does not seem to apply to the geocoding api.

Comment: This however does not work after a few thousand requests. In my case Google has blocked my IP. I still cannot use a key and get the geolocation data using an address. The doc says 2500 requests per day for a free user. Have you faced this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

From your example, you seem to be trying to geolocate UK postcodes. 
You don't need google API to do so, you can download the UK Postcode list, put it in a database and use Google as a fallback option. 
I would recommend to download it from here https://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes.php

Answer (score 0):

You might mismatched the error while transfer it from one source to another.

Try the following url,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=LS2+9AQ&sensor=false&key=[your_key]
```

If still issue occurs then you have to try with another api key as well.