# Google maps geocoding not allowing any requests

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I'm having serious issues with Maps api.

I'm doing a PHP curl request to Geocoder

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=my-key-goes-here&address='.urlencode($address).'&sensor=false&region='.Session::Instance()->get('country'));
```

Everything was working fine for last year or so. Since yesterday I'm getting this error:

```
{ "error_message" : "This site or IP is not authorized to use this API key.", "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }
```

For my `Key for server applications` I have `Any IP allowed` so I don't understand the reason for this error message. Even when I change it and allow my server IP address I still get the same error message.

When I regenerate the key I get an error "The provided API key is expired.". It was just generated, how come it's expiring?

Additionally when I look at my requests it says I've used 0%. I have billing set up on my account but I've never been billed for requests.

I'm clueless. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
The only idea that comes to my mind is that my server has been banned, which I don't understand since I have billing set up :(

When I remove the `key` from my request I get the message of "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API." How can I add billing options so my services continue to work and I can pay for extra requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The basic Google Maps API service is free and no key is required. And the non-descriptive error message 'This site or IP is not authorized to use this API key' is what someone would see using a key from when the service required one.

If you are using up you quota, you can get a business account. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing

BUT, you should be able to optimize your number of calls. Google's daily free quota of 2500 calls is based on a per IP address. If you are doing the calls from PHP then all the calls are coming from your server! Try moving the API calls into client code (e.g., JavaScript).

Google publishes a very good article on how to optimize your server vs. client side strategy. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

Comment: It seems I have answered this question before in another posting as well, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526091/google-maps-api-key-error/20527492#20527492